# Is there an idiom about wasting money and a window?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, translation

Is there an equivalent to the french idiom

> *Jeter l'argent par la fenêtre*

which means throwing money through a window?  (I'm not sure about the translation, especially *through*.)

Comment: Nothing about throwing it through a window, no. "Pour money down the drain", "spend like a sailor", and "money burns a hole in his pocket" are three similar ones.

Comment: http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jeter_l%E2%80%99argent_par_les_fen%C3%AAtres

Comment: There's a similar idiom in German: "Geld beim Fenster rauswerfen" (literally: "to throw money out the window"). I don't know of an English one, 'though.

Comment: @RegDwighт thanks, I didn't know I could get idioms translation from there!

Comment: "Down the toilet" or "down a rathole" are two more.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Isn't it "Geld *zum* Fenster rauswerfen"?

Comment: @Em1: your version is about 10:1 more common according to Google, but I definitely heard "beim" a few times.

Comment: One might **translate** this as *pitch [or throw] your money out the window", to preserve the French idiom, and it would not be perceived as unidiomatic; but the phrases in the answers are more likely to arise in ordinary native speech.

Comment: Despite user21497’s comment above, I would definitely consider “money out the window” a more or less established idiom in English as well. Established enough, at least, that it’s the title of [a 1993 episode of _Family Matters_](http://familymatters.wikia.com/wiki/Money_Out_the_Window).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most commonly-used equivalent English phrase is:

> [Pouring/throwing money down the drain](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pour+money+down+the+drain)
>
> *Fig.* to waste money; to throw money away. "What a waste! Buying that
>   old car is just pouring money down the drain. Don't buy any more of
>   that low-quality merchandise. That's just *throwing money down the drain*."

Answer (score 4):

I have often heard other American English speakers say, "that's just like throwing [or tossing] money out the window" when referring to someone wasting time or resources (eg - not closing a door in winter), or buying unnecessary items or services.  I don't remember the last time I heard this phrase said, but don't believe that this english idiom has gone out of use.  I am 55, and idioms - like slang - do go out of favor over time and/or enter regular use after people hear the popular actors or celebrities of the day say them on TV or in the movies, hear popular singers use them in song lyrics, or see or hear them used in current books, media or advertisements.

Comment: I have also heard and used "throwing money out the window" in english.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more "colourful" version is to **flush your money down the toilet**.

See http://www.google.com.au/search?q=flushing+money+down+the+toilet

Answer (score 0):

There are so many that have similar meanings. Here's one about money and a train:

> It's like tossing money off the back of a train.

Answer (score -3):

or ....its like counting money in the shower....

Comment: A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer. Expert partial answers are welcome, but notions, trial balloons, offhand ideas, guesses, anecdotes, and general discussion are not answers.